# Invalid question numbers/titles (or any other route) bypass the normal 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

I was taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-to-match-dot-character-at-the-end-in-a-route) and used the current URL as a quick test, this gives an actual ASP.Net error page:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426.
```

And this gives an empty page (0 content length):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426..
```

---

The same happens if the title is included as well., this works:

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/title
```

ASP.Net Error Page:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/title.
```

Empty response:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/title..
```

---

I'm not sure what the desired behavior is here, but it seems like a 404 for the non-matching routes would be the appropriate page, just to keep things consistent.  I agree this is a very minor issue with no real consequences, just pointing it out in case someone's digging around in the routes later and wants to make this match.

Comment: +1, repro'd.  SE sites seem to have their fair share of issues with URL rewriting.

Answer (score 3):

Now that we have upgraded to .Net 4 looks like this is fixed.

[It is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-to-match-dot-character-at-the-end-in-a-route...)

Comment: To be fair, I just looked at the question Nick linked to. Credit here goes to @thekaido

Comment: Ugh - I didn't even see the link in @Nick 's question... so late (or early!) here :)